# sigma-algebra generated by the product of $\ell^\infty$

Tags: measure-theory

Can someone give me some hint on the following problem? Many thanks!

Let $\ell^\infty$ denote the set of all bounded real sequences, over which the sup-norm is defined, say, for any $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}\in \ell^\infty$,

$$d(\{x_n\}, \{y_n\})=\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} |x_n-y_n|.$$

The question is that: Is it true that

$$\mathcal{B}\,(\ell^\infty\times \ell^\infty)=\mathcal{B}\,(\ell^\infty)\otimes \mathcal{B}\,(\ell^\infty)\,?$$

where $\ell^\infty\times \ell^\infty$ is the Cartesian product of two $\ell^\infty$ spaces, and $\mathcal{B}\,(\ell^\infty)\otimes \mathcal{B}\,(\ell^\infty)$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the set $\{A\times B \mathrel| A, B\in \mathcal{B}\,(\ell^\infty)\}$.

Answer (score 1):

According to V.I. Bogachev's book *Measure Theory* (volume 2, page 52), it was proved by Michel Talagrand that the answer is yes, given the [continuum hypothesis.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis)

M. Talagrand, *Est-ce que $\ell^\infty$ est une espace mesurable?* Bull. Sci. Math. 1979, T 103. No. 3, 255-258.

Comment: Many thanks. But where can I find the proof in English?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.